# Template for custom post type when taxonomy is in the URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have custom post type called `books`. This has a category taxonomy, called `book_types`. So, for example:

Books -> Fiction -> Da Vinci Code

- Custom Post Type: Books
- Custom Taxonomy: Book Types (fiction, non fiction, etc)
- Single entry: Da Vinci Code

I have the permalinks structure to be:

```
/books/fiction#da-vinci-code
```

All the books are listed in their taxonomy category page as shown above. Da Vinci Code is just one part of the page for Fiction... as seen from the `#da-vinci-code` hashed value in the URL.

This means the taxonomy template is the important one. So I have a template:

```
template-book_types.php
```

But this doesn't work. WP gives a 404. What am I missing? My code to create the CPT and Taxonomy is below. (And yes, I have flushed the Permalinks many times.)

```
/**
 * Post Type: Books.
 */

$labels = [
    "name" => __( "Books", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Book", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
];

$args = [
    "label" => __( "Books", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
    "has_archive" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "delete_with_user" => false,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "can_export" => true,
    "rewrite" => [ "slug" => "books", "with_front" => true ],
    "query_var" => true,
    "menu_position" => 5,
    "menu_icon" => "dashicons-schedule",
    "supports" => [ "title", "editor" ],
    "taxonomies" => [ "book_types" ],
    "show_in_graphql" => false,
];

register_post_type( "books", $args );






/**
 * Taxonomy: Book Types.
 */

$labels = [
    "name" => __( "Book Types", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Book Type", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
];


$args = [
    "label" => __( "Book Types", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "query_var" => true,
    "rewrite" => [ 'slug' => 'book_types', 'with_front' => true, ],
    "show_admin_column" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "show_tagcloud" => false,
    "rest_base" => "book_types",
    "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
    "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
    "sort" => false,
    "show_in_graphql" => false,
];
register_taxonomy( "book_types", [ "books" ], $args );
```

Comment: If you're actually referring to the **post type** archive, then the template name should be `archive-books.php`, but even so, `/books/fiction` would not show 404 error if there's a post with `fiction` as the slug, in your `books` CPT.

Comment: This is a bilingual (PolyLang) site. Funnily, the English works fine but the second language doesn't. There's no template with specifically English names in there. I'm first trying this with the overall templates like `archive.php` or `single.php`. In this case, why does it work with one language and not with the other?

Comment: @SallyCJ in your example `fiction` won't be a post in books, it's the category (`book_types` taxonomy).

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with Polylang, and as for the "fiction" thing, I understand, but what I meant is, if there *was* a **post** (in your CPT) with the *slug being `fiction`*, then `/books/fiction` would have not shown a 404 page, because `books` is the rewrite base *for your CPT*. Also, if `/book_types/fiction#da-vinci-code` doesn't work, then try `/en/book_types/fiction#da-vinci-code` or whatever the correct language-based path set via Polylang. (and note that the `/en/` isn't the "prefix" mentioned in my revised answer)

Answer (score 1):

Your taxonomy's **rewrite base** is actually `book_types` (see the `"rewrite" => [ 'slug' => 'book_types', 'with_front' => true, ]` in your code), so the taxonomy archive pages are accessible at the `/book_types/<term slug>` path.. and not `/books/<term slug>`. So it's normal if `/books/fiction` shows a 404 error page, unless of course if there's a post with the slug `fiction`.

Secondly, note that `'with_front' => true` means if your **Custom Structure** setting on the Permalink Settings admin page uses a *prefix* like `/blog/` (with or without the leading/first slash), then your taxonomy's terms would also have that prefix in the permalink, e.g. `https://example.com/blog/book_types/fiction/`.

And the same also applies to post types where the `with_front` is set to `true`. So for example, `https://example.com/blog/books/da-vinci-code/` would be the permalink for the "Da Vinci Code" post.

So as for the 404 error in question, try loading `/book_types/fiction#da-vinci-code` instead and check if you're seeing the *correct taxonomy archive*.

Also, you should know that the template name for a **taxonomy archive** should actually be in this form: `taxonomy-<taxonomy>.php` — or `taxonomy-<taxonomy>-<term>.php` for a specific term in a taxonomy, so you should rename your template from `template-book_types.php` to `taxonomy-book_types.php` so that WordPress loads it correctly on the taxonomy archive.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/ for more details.

Comment: Thanks. What should I change in my code to have `/books/fiction#da-vinci-code` as the URLs? I don't want the literal word `book_types` as a URL bit. (PS: The 'taxonomy-' prefix gives the same error.)

Comment: Should I make the `'with_front' => false` in the `book_types` if I don't tangibly want this specific phrase, but only the values of book_types in my URLs? I might have misunderstood what `with_front` meant.

Comment: If you want the taxonomy and CPT to **share the same *rewrite base***, i.e. `books`, then note that doing so will lead to a conflict, but you can post another question for more on that. And as for the 404 issue and regarding `with_front`, I have revised my answer, so check it out.